# VBA MSHTML TextInput Click Failed

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, mshtml

I've worked on multiple web-scraping projects using Excel VBA before, but I haven't encountered this problem before. I've been googling the issue for the past few hours, but I haven't found a solution yet.

**Scenario:**
My webpage consists of a list-box and a text box that acts as a filter/search. Unfortunately, I can't disclose the webpage information, but somewhere in the list box elements I saw the word "JQuery". After creating an HTMLInputElement, I set it to text box object and changed its value to "TEXT". I expected the list to get update, but nothing happened. I tried to use different approaches, but they all failed.

```
Text_Field.Focus
Text_Field.FireEvent "onclick"
Text_Field.Value = "TEXT"
Text_Field.Click
```

I managed to put the text in the text box, but the clicking part does not work. When I do it manually, as soon as I type the phrase into the text box, the list gets updated immediately. Any thoughts or suggestions?

I tried to simulate the "enter key" press, but it didn't work either.

Your help will be appreciated.

Best,
Arman

Comment: Can we test against this URL and/or can you include enough HTML for us to have a decent go at debugging please?

Answer (score 0):

Event won't fire when you operate elements programmatically. you have to simulate the events too, using document.createEventObject/inputElement.fireEvent (IE8 or lower) or document.createEvent/inputElement.dispatchEvent (IE9+).

What event you need to fire depends on what the script is interested in (onkeypress, onblur, onpaste, etc).

Comment: To be honest, I'm still trying and googling, but I keep failing. Is there a way to type things rather than assigning the string to the input text box?

Comment: y, sendkeys. but it is kinda unreliable.